# JAVA-11 - security info in SOAP header request does not pass to webservice

Tags: web-services, gradle, java-8, java-11, soapheader

Following code works perfectly fine when compiled with JAVA-8 but does not work when compiled in JAVA-11.
My project is a gradle build project. Inside this project I call a web service passing authentication details in the SOAP header.

When I trace the project in Wireshark, the difference I noticed in JAVA-8 compiled version and JAVA-11 compiled version is that SOAP Header doesn't add to the request in JAVA-11 compiled version hence getting the following error in the server.log also the response from the web service fails as the authentication details are missing in the header part.

server.log

```
2021-07-22 09:15:20,585 WARNING [com.sun.xml.ws.wspolicy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector] (default task-1) WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SupportingTokens" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
2021-07-22 09:15:20,585 WARNING [com.sun.xml.ws.wspolicy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector] (default task-1) WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
```

following are the two dependancies I use:-

```
[group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.3.4'],
[group: 'com.sun.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-ri', version: '2.3.4']
```

SOAP Header is created as in the below class -

```
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;

public abstract class AbstractHeaderProxy {
    protected String endpoint;
    protected static final String ENDPOINT_ADDRESS = "javax.xml.ws.service.endpoint.address";
    public static final String WS_USERNAME = "ws-security.username";
    public static final String WS_PASSWORD = "ws-security.password";

    public void setupPort() {
        final PropertyConfigData commnProps = getCommonProperties();
        final String endpoint = "http://10.20.9.44:80/INVDetails/INVDetailsV2?WSDL";
        final String username = "abc";
        final String password = "abc123";

        getPortBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS, endpoint);
        getPortBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put(WS_USERNAME, username);
        getPortBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put(WS_PASSWORD, password);
    }

    public abstract String getEndPoint();

    public abstract BindingProvider getPortBindingProvider();
}
```

Is there some dependencies I'm missing for JAVA-11?
Or is there a way I can create this SOAP Header in a different way so it attaches to the request?